# What should you consider when scaling a set of databases that must synchronise data?

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have a MongoDB db and have just set up elasticsearch to handle full text search on subsets of that data (e.g. titles of pages, a bit like functionality on Wikipedia).

I have implemented this most likely naively, using Logstash to sync every 10 seconds (every 10s, the title field of any new documents is copied into elasticsearch index).

As of implementation, I found an [article](https://code.likeagirl.io/5-different-ways-to-synchronize-data-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-d8456b83d44f) discussing other methods to sync the two databases, as well as reading one person implementing a python script to sync for them (this idea is appealing).

I was wondering whether anyone with experience in this area could let me know what methods are most scalable and what their preferred method has been so far.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [change stream](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/python-change-streams/) to get a stream of all document changes then you can feed those documents into Elastic Search.

If you are hosted in Atlas we will build a full text index automatically using our built in [Atlas Search tool](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search) (which is built on Lucene).